# Detach screen in screen?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnu-screen

I like to have a screen session set up with two windows side by side (Ctrl+A | key combo).  The issue is that sometimes I need to run a server that starts a screen session in the foreground of one of my screen sessions.  So now I have a screen session in another screen session.  When I try to detach the inner screen (Ctrl+A d), it detaches the outerscreen.

Is there any solution to detaching only the screen in the outer screen session?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The screen man page explains

```
   C-a a       (meta)        Send the command character (C-a)  to  window.
                             See escape command.
```

So you should be able to detach the inner screen by typing C-a a d (without spaces).

Comment: Its been a year, but THANKS!!!